# Can't navigate to specific folder in Google Colab without "Errno 2"

Tags: python, cd, google-colaboratory

Apologies if this is a very beginner question but I'm trying to change directory from  `/content/drive/testing/catdeform/code/util/figure_code'` to `content/drive/testing/catdeform/code`

My steps so far have not helped the situation.
When I did:

`%cd drive`

I got:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'drive'
/content/drive/testing/catdeform/code/util/figure_code'
```

Then I did

`$cd ~`

and it gave output `root` in the Colab cell console.

Now if I try, for example,

`%cd /drive/testing/catdeform/code`

it gives output:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/drive/testing/catdeform/code'
/root
```

And if I do `%cd code` then that gives me

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/code'
/root
```

I'm very confused. How do I just go into `'/drive/testing/catdeform/code'` folder without issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to start off the call with /content/ to specifically go somewhere. So,

`%cd /content/drive/testing/catdeform/code/`

finally got me in the right spot. I hope this method continues to work for me!